# Run program on different network adapter

Tags: networking

I want to run some programs on wlan0, but run others on eth0. Is there any way to tell a certain process to run on X and Y? Or how would someone go about doing this? If it's even possible.

Comment: It depends. Please clarify which programs.

Comment: Any process on the system.

Comment: It might be possible, maybe through manipulating the routing table. But I don't know how.